# create new column based on condition in column of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing column of lists:

```
col_1            
[A, A, A, B, C]
[D, B, C]
[C]
[A, A, A]
NaN
```

I want to create new column, if the list starts with 3* `A` return 1, if not return 0:

```
col_1              new_col           
[A, A, A, B, C]    1
[D, B, C]          0
[C]                0
[A, A, A]          1
NaN                0
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
df['new_col'] = df.loc[df.col_1[0:3] == [A, A, A]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beause there are some non list values is possible use `if-else` lambda function for `0` if not list:

```
print (df['col_1'].map(type))
0     <class 'list'>
1     <class 'list'>
2     <class 'list'>
3     <class 'list'>
4    <class 'float'>
Name: col_1, dtype: object
```

---

```
f = lambda x: int((x[:3]) == ['A','A','A']) if isinstance(x, list) else 0
df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].map(f)
#alternative
#df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].apply(f)
print (df)
             col_1  new_col
0  [A, A, A, B, C]        1
1        [D, B, C]        0
2              [C]        0
3        [A, A, A]        1
4              NaN        0
```

Comment: thanks, return an error :TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
you think from the NaN's ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa - What is `print (df['col_1'].map(type))` ?

Comment: @khaledkoubaa - If there are strings instead lists is possible use `df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')` before my solution for lists

Answer (score 2):

Here is another potential  solution using `map`:

```
import pandas as pd

#borrowing dataframe from @Alexendra
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [
      ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
      ['D', 'B', 'C'],
      ['C'],
      ['A', 'A', 'A']
    ]
})

df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].map(lambda x : 1  if x[0:3] == ['A','A','A']   else 0)

print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
             col_1  new_col
0  [A, A, A, B, C]        1
1        [D, B, C]        0
2              [C]        0
3        [A, A, A]        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution via apply lambda:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [          
      ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
      ['D', 'B', 'C'],
      ['C'],
      ['A', 'A', 'A']
    ]
})

df['new_col'] = df.col_1.apply(lambda x: x[0:3] == ['A', 'A', 'A'] if isinstance(x, list) else False).view('i1')

df.head()
```

Output:

[image: Output]